# Trying to run SSIS project with Teradata in windows container. Unable to install TTU on Windows Container

Tags: windows, containers, teradata

I am unable to install Teradata tools and utilities in Windows image. (helloworld-nanoserver:1809).
setup.bat needs UI and there is no silent_setup.bat for installation.
Can I check if there is any Teradata tools and utilities Windows Docker Image or is there any way TTU can be installed in Windows Image ?

```
C:\TeradataToolsAndUtilitiesBase>dir
 
Volume in drive C has no label.

 Volume Serial Number is 5067-130B

 Directory of C:\TeradataToolsAndUtilitiesBase

01/30/2022  10:33 PM    <DIR>          .

01/30/2022  10:33 PM    <DIR>          ..

01/30/2022  10:33 PM               249 license_new.txt

01/30/2022  10:33 PM    <DIR>          Readmes

01/30/2022  10:33 PM               866 setup.bat

01/30/2022  10:33 PM    <DIR>          TeraJDBC

01/30/2022  10:33 PM    <DIR>          Windows

               2 File(s)          1,115 bytes

               5 Dir(s)  20,182,740,992 bytes free


C:\TeradataToolsAndUtilitiesBase>setup.bat

C:\TeradataToolsAndUtilitiesBase>
```

Comment: The `silent_install.bat` is located in the ...\Windows\TTU folder, not in the root folder for the suite.

Comment: Windows folder was already present in the running pod

Comment: Don't understand the last comment. The script is In the folder within the (unzipped) install package for the Teradata Tools and Utilities Base suite.